Проблема с пакетами в PyCharm (Ошибка ModuleNotFoundError: No module named)
Структура проекта:
-app_api_v1(package)
 |-__init_.py
 |-main.py
-database_api(package)
 |-__init_.py
 |-config.py
 |-db_settings.py
 |-models.py
 |-orm.py

__int__.py в database_api
from .orm import seralizer_data

Когда я пытаюсь запустить файл main.py через терминал в PyCharm, мне выдает ошибку:
from database_api import seralizer_data
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'database_api'

Но когда я запускаю именно через PyCharm, все работает отлично.
Никак не могу найти решения, подскажите пожалуйста.

PyCharm использует source root в качестве стартовой точки для импорта: mark as source root.
Почитайте также про namespace-packages.

Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.

Понял, принято :)
